# Itemize bullets are not shown in beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

I am trying to do a list with itemize in beamer and the bullets are not shown. I've read some comments here that the enumitem package might be the problem but I don't use it so I don't why this is happening. I would be glad if someone can have a look at my preamble and stress what's the problem. Here is my preamble code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,hyperref={breaklinks=true},mathserif,professionalfont,12pt]{beamer} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usecolortheme[named=RoyalBlue]{structure} 
\useoutertheme{infolines} 
\usetheme[height=7mm]{Rochester} 
\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertsubsection
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning}
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={
    rectangle, 
    rounded corners,
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=red!30
    },process/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=blue!30
    },
  decision/.style={
    rectangle, 
    minimum width=3cm, 
    minimum height=1cm, align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
  arrow/.style={draw,thick,->,>=stealth},
  dec/.style={
    ellipse, 
    align=center, 
    draw=black, 
    fill=green!30
    },
}
%\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}%margins
%\usepackage{amsmath}%math..
\usepackage{graphicx}%graphics
\usepackage{refstyle}%refstyle
\usepackage{float}%graphs floating
\usepackage{subcaption}%subcaption
\usepackage{makecell}%tables
\usepackage{diagbox}%diagonal tables
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}%ref
\usepackage[redeflists]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{ucs}
```

Thanks,
Roi

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. To be able to help you we need to be able to recreate the problem. We need a Minimal Working Example: A short code (as short as possible) that recreates the problem, beginning with `\documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: I would suspect `\usepackage[redeflists]{IEEEtrantools}` as beamer uses its own list definitions. Since IEEEtrantools is not beamer aware, I would probably not use it with beamer

Comment: Thank you daleif! It worked!!

Comment: @daleif Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz done. Is it you going through all these beamer questions at the moment?

Comment: @daleif yes, I'm looking through a couple of unanswered question.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
\usepackage[redeflists]{IEEEtrantools}
```

redefines list in a manner not expected by `beamer` and like `enumitem` probably should not be used with `beamer`.